# Swap ETH for Tokens and Back on Remix

Tags: remix, uniswap

I'm just trying to create a simple smart contract which can swap eth for tokens, and then swap those tokens for ETH back.

This is my code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: agpl-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

interface IUniswap {
    function swapExactTokensForETH(
        uint amountIn, 
        uint amountOutMin, 
        address[] calldata path, 
        address to, 
        uint deadline)
    external
    returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    
    function swapExactETHForTokens(
            uint amountOutMin, 
            address[] calldata path, 
            address to, 
            uint deadline)
        external
        payable
    returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    
    function WETH() external pure returns (address);
}

interface IERC20 {
    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) external returns (bool);
    
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract EzSwap {
    IUniswap uniswap;
    
    constructor(address _uniswap) {
        uniswap = IUniswap(_uniswap);
    }
    
    function swapExactETHForTokens(
        address token,
        uint amountOutMin, 
        uint deadline) external payable {
            
            address[] memory path = new address[](2);
            path[0] = uniswap.WETH();
            path[1] = token;
            
            uniswap.swapExactETHForTokens{value: msg.value}(
                amountOutMin,
                path,
                msg.sender,
                deadline);
    }
        
    // uniswap address 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D
    function swapTokensForETH(
        address token, 
        uint amountIn, 
        uint amountOutMin, 
        uint deadline) external {
            IERC20(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountIn);
            address[] memory path = new address[](2);
            path[0] = token;
            path[1] = uniswap.WETH();
            IERC20(token).approve(address(uniswap), amountIn);
            uniswap.swapExactTokensForETH(amountIn, amountOutMin, path, msg.sender, deadline);
    }
}
```

When I try to execute `swapExactETHForTokens` I get an error:

> false Transaction mined but execution failed

**Edit:**

I'm using this address for the UniswapV2(`0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D`)

```
token = '0x5592EC0cfb4dbc12D3aB100b257153436a1f0FEa' //DAI Address
amountOutMin = 1   //Arbirary value that should always pass
Deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 10 // calculating deadline from current timestamp
Value = 90 // In ETH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything, it should work, maybe router address is incorrect
`IUniswapV2Router02(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D)` or maybe transaction `value` is not enough to buy `amountOutMin` or that token does not have Pool or Liquidity Provider

Make sure you're using the right RPC.
Change the Environment to `InjectedWeb3Provider`
and Set Your Infura RPC in the window

Comment: i'm using that address, I set the value to 99 eth and amountOut for Dai as 1.  I just want any transaction to pass so I know it works :/

Comment: calculate `amountOutMin` by ```uint256[] memory amounts = _router.getAmountsOut(value, path);``` and send ETH as WEI 90ETH = 90000000000000000000. `amountOutMin = amounts[1];`